# EventBridge notification on Amazon s3 folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

I have to start stepMachine execution upon file upload on a folder inside bucket, I got to know how we can configure eventbridge on S3 bucket level. But on the same bucket there can be multiple file uploads. I need to get notified when object inserted into a particular folder inside bucket. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 14):

Here is another solution. Since folders technically do not exist in S3 and merely a UI feature, "folders" in S3 are ultimately called prefixes.

You can trigger an EventBridge Notification on an S3 folder with the following event pattern:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["<bucket-name>"]
    },
    "object": {
      "key": [{
        "prefix": "<prefix/folder-name>"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The documentation isn't particularly clear on running matches on nested objects, so this was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an [EventBridge Filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns-content-based-filtering.html) to only send the events when the S3 object's prefix matches your folder name.