# EventBridge pattern invalid when I add a path prefix. "Event pattern is not valid. Reason: "name" must be an object or an array at..."

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to create and EventBridge event that triggers when objects are created in a path prefix of my bucket. When I write the event pattern without the path prefix, it works. When I add the path prefix, I get a failure. I am using [official documentation for syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ev-events.html) and [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72725831/eventbridge-notification-on-amazon-s3-folder) seems to confirm what I'm doing but the solution doesn't work.

I am using EventBridge to create the rule > Step 2 Build event pattern > Event pattern.

- Error message:

*Event pattern is not valid. Reason: "name" must be an object or an array at [Source: (String)"{"source":["aws.s3"],"detail-type":["Object Created"],"detail":{"bucket":{"name":"test-test-20230118"},"object":{"key":[{"prefix":"raw"}]}}}"; line: 1, column: 83]*

- Unsuccessful pattern:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["test-test-20230118"]
    },
    "object": {
      "key": [{
        "prefix": "raw"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

- Successful pattern without prefix:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["test-test-20230118"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern will work if you modify the sample event to match the name and prefix your filtering on. Ive not seen that error so not sure whats going on but i think its related to the sample event your testing your pattern against. Start again with the sample event (I copied the sample event from event type -> AWS Events, sample events -> Object Created and pasted it into "enter my own") and update resources, bucket->name and detail->object->key so your pattern will match it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume "raw" is a directory in your "test-test-20230118" bucket. If that is the case, use a slash such as "raw/" as prefix.

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "detail": {
    "bucket": {
      "name": ["test-test-20230118"]
    },
    "object": {
      "key": [{
        "prefix": "raw/"
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the pattern **worked** for my path prefix aka folders:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.s3"],
  "detail-type": ["Object Created"],
  "resources": ["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"],
  "detail": {
    "object": {
      "key": [{"wildcard": "PREFIX_NAME/*.*"}]
    }
  }
}
```

Please replace **BUCKET_NAME** and **PREFIX_NAME** with your bucket and prefix.  I used the event pattern rules from here:

[Amazon EventBridge event patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns.html)